# Cannot recognize wired or wireless connection

Tags: installation, wireless, networking, internet, wired

I just installed ubuntu 13.04 on an old laptop of mine and I can't connect to the internet. the computer is a Dell Vostro 1500.

This is my first time using Linux so I really have no idea what I am doing, but I'm trying to learn.

I know This has probably been posted a bunch of times but after looking through several I couldn't find any with the same problem

```
lspci

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile PM965/GM965/GL960 Memory Controller Hub (rev 0c)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (primary) (rev 0c)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (secondary) (rev 0c)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 02)
00:1a.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 (rev 02)
00:1a.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 (rev 02)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 02)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 02)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 2 (rev 02)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 4 (rev 02)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 02)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 02)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 02)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 (rev 02)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev f2)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801HM (ICH8M) LPC Interface Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801HM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) IDE Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801HM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 02)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 02)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4401-B0 100Base-TX (rev 02)
03:01.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Ricoh Co Ltd R5C832 IEEE 1394 Controller (rev 05)
03:01.1 SD Host controller: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C822 SD/SDIO/MMC/MS/MSPro Host Adapter (rev 22)
03:01.2 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C592 Memory Stick Bus Host Adapter (rev 12)
03:01.3 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd xD-Picture Card Controller (rev 12)
0c:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN (rev 01)
```

.

```
ifconfig

Link encap:Local Loopback  
inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
RX packets:3529 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:3529 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
RX bytes:289936 (289.9 KB)  TX bytes:289936 (289.9 KB)
```

.

```
~$ sudo ifconfig
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:8601 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8601 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:708816 (708.8 KB)  TX bytes:708816 (708.8 KB)
```

.

```
~$ sudo iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.
```

Comment: Please add the complete output of `sudo ifconfig` and also add the result of `sudo iwconfig` to your question

Comment: Okay I added those. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to this link, the driver is in post 8. [b43.zip](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2117874)

Download the b43 zip file to a flash drive then drag and drop the file to your ubuntu desktop. Right-click it and select Extract Here. Open a terminal and do:

```
sudo mkdir /lib/firmware/b43

sudo cp Desktop/b43/* /lib/firmware/b43

sudo rmmod -f b43

sudo rmmod -f ssb

sudo modprobe b43
```

if you have not installed any other wireless driver your wireless should now be working.

These directions are for installing the driver without internet connection

You have another driver installed so we need to remove it.

```
sudo apt-get purge --remove bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Then:

```
sudo modprobe b43
```

Comment: Thank you I did what you said and the first 2 commands seemed to work corectly. however when I put in the third command I got this '~$ sudo rmmod -f b43
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:753 kmod_module_remove_module: could not remove 'b43': No such file or directory
Error: could not remove module b43: No such file or directory'

Comment: do the rest of the commands or reboot and it should work. If it does please accept the answer so others can benefit.

Comment: @Wild Man Your code is slightly wrong and I edited the question with the correct code.Awaiting approval. Same mistake as [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2117874) check post#9 :-)

Comment: Alright @WildMan I did that but I get error messages for commands 3 and 4. Command five doesn't give me anything.

Comment: @JonathanRogiest Where is the correct code?

Comment: The reason you get errors is because the drivers are not loaded so they cannot be unloaded, do not worry about that the last command you will only see a message if there is an error so it must have worked. Go to top right corner of the screen and create a wireless connection and make sure wireless is enabled.

Comment: @Taydoco [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2117874) post #9 from Chili555. Try those commands.

Comment: @Taydoco the change is not needed because I used a different command structure then the one chili555 was correcting. Those commands did not fail he did not receive an error message.

Comment: Please open the terminal(ctrl+alt+t) run the commands one line at a time: `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net`
`lsusb`
`nm-tool`
`sudo iwlist scan`
`iwconfig`
`rfkill list all`
`lsmod`                              `dmesg | egrep 'b43|wl|firm|wlan|network|wpa'` post the output at http://pastebin.com/ then post the link here. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan Rogiest when I edited after posted the command got lost in the process.

Comment: Okay @WildMan This is it. http://pastebin.com/5SmcQdwE

Comment: Please do `sudo modprobe -rv wl` `sudo modprobe -v b43` does it come on? if so I will add the answer above to make it permanent.

Comment: no it doesn't seem to work. the firs command gave me FATAL: Module wl is in use. and the second command gave me: insmod /lib/modules/3.8.0-19-generic/kernel/drivers/ssb/ssb.ko

Comment: Did you create an account and downloaded the b43.zip file from ubuntuforums?

Comment: I added more commands to my answer.

Comment: @WildMan Alright I Put in those two commands and the first one did what is was supposed to do (I believe) and the second one gave me nothing in response and it says the process is still running if I try to close the terminal. No internet connections seem to appear. Just to be clear I have it connected via Ethernet wire, the wi-fi switch is turned on and "Enable Networking" is checked. The network should appear in the drop-down after I click on the signal icon at the top right correct?

Comment: Yes the network should appear at the top right. It should also have an enable wireless tab along with the enable networking tab. As long as the ethernet is plugged in it will override the wireless connection. The commands I asked you to run in comments above start with `lsusb` and post the output of all the commands to pastebin, please notice that there is white space between each command so do not run them together this time and that way we can see all the information so it might help us to know what is wrong.

Comment: @WildMan here you go http://pastebin.com/55q6RxcY  I tried to space the commands out more in the pastebin.

Comment: Please add the output of: `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net` to your answer.

Comment: @WildMan okay I added it to the bottom of the pastbin here. http://pastebin.com/EeTkKENT

Comment: Please run the last two commands in my answer the first one should get rid of the wl driver and the second should load the b43, post the output of those commands to pastebin so we can see if they fail. The last command will only show output if it fails.

Comment: @WildMan here http://pastebin.com/4m9BUSYk  It ends with my cursor on an empty line.

Comment: Please post the output of: `ls -al /lib/firmware/b43`

Comment: @WildMan http://pastebin.com/v6DD3Drm

Comment: That looks good, if you have not done so please reboot then post the output of: `sudo iwlist scan` `rfkill list all` `lsmod | grep b43`

Comment: Sweet It's working! Here is the command outputs if you still wanted to see them http://pastebin.com/RHzddnPi Thank you so much @WildMan !